# MySQL combining data from three queries

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to combine these queries so that I get a distinct name, then the quantity for today, tomorrow, and the day after tomorrow

```
select name, SUM(qty) as qty_today, 0 as qty_tomororow, 0 as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date = '2011-11-22'
group by name
union all
select name, qty as qty_today, SUM(qty) as qty_tomororow, 0 as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date = '2011-11-23'
group by name
union all
select name, 0 as qty_today, 0 as qty_tomororow, SUM(qty) as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date = '2011-11-24'
group by name
```

**UPDATE**
Given the table
name, qty, delivery_date
Chicago, 1, 2011-11-22
New York, 2, 2011-11-22
Chicago, 3, 2011-11-23

I would expect
Chicago, 1, 3, 0
New York, 1, 0, 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to combine all of them in one dataset you can try this,

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN delivery_date = '2011-11-22' THEN qty 
                ELSE 0 END) AS qty_today,
       SUM(CASE WHEN delivery_date = '2011-11-23' THEN qty 
                ELSE 0 END) AS qty_tomororow,
       SUM(CASE WHEN delivery_date = '2011-11-24' THEN qty 
                ELSE 0 END) AS qty_om
from order_item
where delivery_date between '2011-11-22' and '2011-11-24'
group by name
```

This would work in TSQL (MS SQL), hopefully it's the same syntax in MySql

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, SUM(qty) as qty_today, 0 as qty_tomororow, 0 as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date IN ('2011-11-22', '2011-11-23', '2011-11-24')
group by delivery_date, name
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` / `UNION ALL` will do the trick:

```
select name, SUM(qty) as qty_today, 0 as qty_tomororow, 0 as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date = '2011-11-22'
group by name
UNION ALL
select name, qty as qty_today, SUM(qty) as qty_tomororow, 0 as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date = '2011-11-23'
group by name
UNION ALL
select name, 0 as qty_today, 0 as qty_tomororow, SUM(qty) as qty_om  
from order_item
where delivery_date = '2011-11-24'
group by name
```

Comment: That said, looks like you should `GROUP BY delivery_date, name` instead.

Comment: this seems close. do I need to wrap this all in another query to collapse into distinct names and then SUM() against all three qty fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(if (delivery_date = '2011-11-22' , qty , 0) ) AS qty_today,
       SUM(if (delivery_date = '2011-11-23' , qty , 0) ) AS qty_tomororow,
       SUM(if (delivery_date = '2011-11-24' , qty , 0) ) AS qty_om
from order_item group by name
```

This is MySQL more style